# Calling Rest Api(Hosted in salesforce) from MuleSoft

Tags: rest, mulesoft

In one of my implementation I need to call a Rest base webservice (which is developed in salesforce) from Mulesoft.I am able to call other Rest URI (eg.Yahoo etc) but when I am trying to call Salesforce Rest URI(which needs authentacation)then it is throwing me error.

```
Message               : Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: NullPayload
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. null (java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException)
  org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl$Sync:357 (null)
2. Error sending HTTP request. Message payload is of type: NullPayload (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
  org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester:190 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
```

In above case I have additionally configured TSL and basic authentication salesforce

Also I tried with Oauth. But in this case also I am NullPayload Error.
Can any one guide us the Steps to follow.

Comment: @vamsi krishna HI - where you able to find a solution to this problem